# How should I properly use unittest.mock.patch to use a fake object in a unit test?

Tags: python

I've been looking into using unittest.mock to replace an object with a fake (as a toy project, as it seems interesting). Part way down the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), there's an example of replacing an object with an `io.StringIO` instance, so I can see that in theory this should work, but I can't get a particular toy example to work without having to jump through some additional hoops. Consider this code, saved as `main.py`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class FileSystem:

    def __init__(self, filename="file.txt"):
        self.filename = filename

    def write(self, content):
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(content)

    def read(self):
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            return f.read()

class FileSystemFake:

    def __init__(self, filename="file.txt"):
        self.filename = filename
        self.content = None
        self.file_exists = False

    def write(self, content):
        self.content = content
        self.file_exists = True

    def read(self):
        if self.file_exists:
            return self.content
        raise FileNotFoundError

class FileSystemFakeHoldingInstance(FileSystemFake):

    instance = None

    @classmethod
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.instance is not None:
            return cls.instance
        cls.instance = FileSystemFakeHoldingInstance(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.instance

def say_hello():
    filesystem = FileSystem("hello.txt")
    filesystem.write("hello")

def test_self_no_patch():
    say_hello()
    with open("hello.txt") as f:
        assert f.read() == "hello"

@patch('main.FileSystem', new_callable=FileSystem)
def test_self(fake):
    say_hello()
    assert fake.read() == "hello"

@patch('main.FileSystem', new_callable=FileSystemFake)
def test_fake(fake):
    say_hello()
    assert fake.read() == "hello"

@patch('main.FileSystem', new_callable=FileSystemFakeHoldingInstance)
def test_fake_holder(fake):
    say_hello()
    assert fake.read() == "hello"

@patch('main.FileSystem', new_callable=FileSystemFakeHoldingInstance)
def test_fake_holder_reference(fake):
    say_hello()
    assert FileSystemFakeHoldingInstance.instance.read() == "hello"
```

The toy example features a class `FileSystem` that saves a file on the file system and reads it back. This class is the one I'm faking out to avoid the file system access. I've made a `FileSystemFake` class, which pretends to save a file and read it back, and a `FileSystemFakeHoldingInstance` class, which holds an instance of `FileSystemFake` and implements a `__call__` method that returns it.

I have a simple test (`test_self_no_patch`) which interacts using the file system and works fine. My first point of confusion happens with `test_self`, which attempts to replace a call to `FileSystem` with a call to `FileSystem` (the same class), but throws "TypeError: 'FileSystem' object is not callable". I put this one in after writing `test_fake`, which replaces `FileSystem` with `FileSystemFake` fails with a similar error: "TypeError: 'FileSystemFake' object is not callable".

The second issue is visible in `test_fake_holder`, where we get a `FileNotFoundError`: by the documentation, the object passed into the function is the created fake. The "write" function runs through fine, but calling "read" on the fake doesn't return the written text.

Finally, in `test_fake_holder_reference`, I read the text from a static instance on the holder, which works.

Why am I seeing this particular behaviour (classes not being callable, patch not returning the "right" object)? Is there a series of parameters I can pass to `patch` to make it work with `FileSystemFake` directly?

Comment: If you can help it, try to avoid writing code that requires patching to test. For example, instead of hard-coding `FileSystem` in `say_hello`, let it take an argument specifying the class to use to implement a file system. Then you can call `say_hello(FileSystem)` or `say_hello(FileSystemFake)` or `say_hello(FileSystemFakeHoldingInstance)` as appropriate.

Comment: I know DI is standard practice, I'm specifically interested in getting this method working because it seems interesting.